# Normal mapping for Android and iOS

Tags: unity, textures, models, normal-mapping

I'm making a mobile game for Android and iOS on Unity. At the moment I am researching and designing the technical aspects of the game. Since it is not plausible to use highly detailed models for mobile platforms, should normal mapped models be used instead?

Thus I have couple of questions about normal mapping. Are normal mapped models much more costly to make, in other words, do they take a lot longer to create? And are they much more expensive to render? At least there are no additional draw calls, but of course the shader is more complex.

Comment: Are you doing shader calculations or want to do a normal map texture?

Comment: In Unity the shaders are already there. I am just wondering how much more time it will take for the artist to create a normal mapped model compared to low-poly texture mapped one.

Comment: My artist is creating normal mapped models for our mobile game and They look great on iPhone and iPad. I didn't feel any performance problem unless I use complex image effects on the camera (Blur, AntialiasPostEffect and such)

Comment: Could you ask your artist about his workflow? In particular how he does the normal mapped models? As one artist said that creating normal mapped models is very time consuming.

Comment: I suggest you read these two articles as a general rule of thumb: - [IPhone Practical Guide](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/iphone-PracticalGuide.html) - [Optimizing Graphics Performance](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/OptimizingGraphicsPerformance.html)

Comment: He is very experienced and working in game industry. I think it will be impossible to transferring his experience into this small comment box. I think you should see some modelling videos. I just answered your question that is, normal maps are very ok with mobile game development.

Comment: That depends on the skillset of the artist, and the quality of the model. Often times artists use tools such as zbrush to sculpt a higher resolution of the model before baking out normal maps. This is a time consuming process, and zbrush is expensive. They sure look great though.

Answer (score 2):

The model itself is not more costly to made but an additional texture is required. Depending on the artist a new texture has to be drawn or the bumpiness is created from a high detail version of the model. The is no general answer.

[Unity states](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/shader-Performance.html)

*Normal mapped. This is a bit more expensive than Diffuse: it adds one more texture (normal map), and a couple of shader instructions.*

Normal mapping is a viable option on mobile platform if you stick to the mobile shaders.